# How relevant is the honeypot technique today?

Tags: honeypot

I have been reading about honeypots and different implementation of them, while some articles are recent most of them are old (more than ten years ago) I was wondering if honeypots are still relevant and used in the industry (used by big companies, infosec professionals etc). I may choose the topic for my undergrad paper based on this.

Comment: Since answers seem to be downvoted, I will write this as an comment. But in short, yes, honeypots are still relevant techniques today. I actively set up an honeypot with a colleague in my previous company. ( 2 years ago )
Additionally it is still actively researched and improved.

Comment: I don't know of any large corporation that doesn't use honeypots in at least one area.

Comment: Interesting talk: https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7277-breaking_honeypots_for_fun_and_profit

Comment: It's still relevant : https://www.gravityforms.com/rip-captcha/

Answer (score 4):

One good way, to find what today's industry is using, it's to track reports as *Magic Quadrant*.

> Magic Quadrant (MQ) refers to a series published by IT consulting firm Gartner of market research reports that rely on proprietary qualitative data analysis methods to demonstrate market trends, such as direction, maturity and participants.
> ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Quadrant))

So, what reports like MQ's saying about deception tools:

> Gartner has predicted that now, in 2018, 10 percent of enterprises will already be using deception tools and tactics and actively participate in deception operations against attackers. They were spot-on accurate. ([source](https://trapx.com/featured-white-paper-gartner-emerging-technology-report/))
>
> Gartner believes that more lean-forward organizations should also leverage deception in-depth as a new strategy for comprehensive threat defense against the onslaught of advanced attackers and attack techniques. Product managers who help product marketing managers articulate the value of deception in their own products or integrations with other deception products can enhance their attractiveness, especially for larger organizations under constant threat, for example, the financial services, healthcare, government and software verticals.
> ([source](http://trapx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Gartner-Reprint.pdf))

To conclude, deception technologies is *not only* a growing technology, but it's been used by most biggest technology companies around.

Answer (score 3):

The area of deception technology (this involves honeypots and honeytokens among others) is actively researched. The [SPACECRAB](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2017/10/project-spacecrab-breach-detection/) project by the Atlassian security team is one example.

Have a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06196) survey to get a detailed overview of various aspects of the deception technology environment.